# ¿Como lleno un combobox sin que me aparesca vacio cuando se carga?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy llenando un combo box atraves de una consulta sql que me devuelve un dataset para ir cargando los datos, el problema que tengo es que necesito llenar este combo sin que aparezca vacío el primer ítem ya que esto me da problema al cargar las bodegas de las tiendas que también es un combo box que se llena con el procedimiento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que uso para llenar el combobox en el load del formulario

```
 Private Sub FrmDespachoProv_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Dim VlDatos As DataSet
    VCerrado = False

    Try
        Dim Vstatus As Integer
        Dim VlDatos1 As DataSet
   
       
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim VlDatos As DataSet

        'Consulta a la base de datos y obtener el dataset con los datos
        VlDatos = CLLibreria.MdlWaVentas.Ventas.BuscaTiendasguia(Vstatus)
        CbbTiendas.DataSource = VlDatos.Tables(0)
        CbbTiendas.DisplayMember = "Descripcion"
        CbbTiendas.ValueMember = "Cod_Tienda"

        VlDatos = Nothing


        ' Si deseas seleccionar el primer elemento automáticamente, puedes hacer lo 
        siguiente
        If CbbTiendas.Items.Count > 0 Then
            CbbTiendas.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If

        

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al cargar pantalla", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Me.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Use una validación para tratar que se tomara el primer dato pero no me funciono como requiero que aparezca

El resultado que necesito es así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esto no anduvo? CbbTiendas.SelectedIndex = 0

Comment: no, lo ejecute asi y tampoco me tomo el index

Comment: probalo en otro metodo, no en el load, probalo en el on_activate u otro metodo posterior...